# How to create a CSV file with PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I have a short question about pyspark write.

```
read_jdbc = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()

read_jdbc.show()
```

When I command show, it works perfectly,

However, when I try to write,

```
read_jdbc.write.csv("some/aaa")
```

it only creates aaa folder, but the CSV is not created.

I also tried

```
read_jdbc.write.jdbc(mysql_url,table="csv_test",mode="append")
```

This does not work either. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

you can write dataframe to csv

```
df.write.csv("file-path")
```

or

```
df.write.format("csv").save("file-path")
```